# Combination in Python

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, combinations

I am trying to understand the Algo of **combinations** function in python

```
def combinations(iterable, r):   
    # combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
    # combinations(range(4), 3) --> 012 013 023 123
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

But I am unable to understand why `if indices[i] != i + n - r:` and
`for j in range(i+1, r):
 indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1`is used in this function what is their role.
Please help me .

Comment: could you fix the indentation, There is no code block after def.

Comment: @navneet Arya are you open to recursive solution ?

Comment: @zenwraight yes open to recursive solution.

Comment: Ok, let me post a solution from scratch.

Comment: thank you so much @zenwraight , I will wait for solution and please explain also .

Answer (score 0):

I think a solution like this will do, what you are trying to achieve

```
combinationDict = []

def combinations(iterable, r, cnt, subPart):
  if cnt > r:
    return
  if cnt == r:
    combinationDict.append(subPart)
    return
  if (len(iterable) < r):
    return  
  i = 0
  while i < len(iterable):
    combinations(iterable[:i]+iterable[i+1:], r, cnt+1, subPart+iterable[i])
    combinations(iterable[:i]+iterable[i+1:], r, cnt, subPart)
    i += 1

combinations("ABCD", 2, 0, "")
print(combinationDict)
```

Basically main aim of the above solution is, at each step of recursion, either to add a particular element at i or don't add it to the combination.

Let's say for example of `ABCD` and `2`, we start with `A`, then we add `B`, then we see size is `2`, we return, we add `C` to `A` as we return back to the recursive call.

Now this, solution has exponential time complexity as it is a brute force solution.

Hope this helps!